# Error of react-diagram caused by @emotion/core

Tags: reactjs, typescript, emotion

i was installing react-diagrams by projectStorm and it is causing errors as below
[errorImg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sjoWQ.png)

I tried to downgrade '@emotion/core' version to ^10.0.0 but it didn't help.
this the img of my package.json -> [package.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ZrpJ.png)

this is the code i wrote according to the official documentation of react-diagram

```
import React from 'react';
import createEngine, {DefaultLinkModel, DefaultNodeModel, DiagramModel } from '@projectstorm/react- 
diagrams';

import { CanvasWidget } from '@projectstorm/react-canvas-core';


const engine = createEngine();

const node1 = new DefaultNodeModel({
    name : 'Node 1',
    color : 'rgb(0, 192, 255)',
});
node1.setPosition(100, 100);

let port1 = node1.addOutPort('Out');

const node2 = new DefaultNodeModel({
    name : 'Node 2',
    color : 'rgb(0, 192, 255)',
});
node2.setPosition(100, 100);

let port2 = node2.addOutPort('Out');

const link = port1.link<DefaultLinkModel>(port2);
link.addLabel('Hello World');

const model = new DiagramModel();

model.addAll(node1, node2, link);
engine.setModel(model);


const DiagramView = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            <CanvasWidget engine = {engine}/>
        </div>
    );
};

export default DiagramView;
```

thank you
[error Img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sjoWQ.png): https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZY5WR.png
[package.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ZrpJ.png): https://i.stack.imgur.com/1iOk5.png

Answer (score 0):

Fixed!

to use the package, @emotion/core's version should be 10.x.x

what i did was

```
 npm remove @emation/core
```

but I had to ***physically remove the file by deleting the folder in the node_modules*** and reinstall the package by

```
npm i @emotion/core@10.0.0
```

moreover, after the error is gone, this line in the official document
caused error so just comment(//) this line and save the file :)
hope this helps somebody

```
link.addLabel('Hello World');
```